# SQL Server Query Store Top Resource Execution Count Incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, sql-query-store

We've enabled query trace in our production database to investigate some performance problems (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908)). While tracking executed queries from query trace, it seems to me like these execution count totals are way off. Attaching a snippet of counts for one minute. I've also looked at the Dynatrace DB call numbers and they seem more accurate to me. Wondering if its incorrect of if I'm looking at this wrong.
Dynatrace screenshot contains 5 mins of data as its the minimum allowed threshold.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it confuses the data set.
Same query, different response below...

[image]

[image]